# TYPO3 extend tt_content with FAL image and display in frontend

Tags: image, typo3, fal

i want to extend the tt_content table with an image. It should be possible to set this image in every content element. This is what i got so far

ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
   tx_layout_background_image int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

TypoScript:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  templateName = TEXT
  templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
  templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = pagelayout
    pagets__kubus_layout = TEXT
    pagets__kubus_layout.value = Default
    default = TEXT
    default.value = Default
  }
  templateRootPaths {
    0 = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/Page/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    0 = {$resDir}/Private/Partials/Page/
  }
  layoutRootPaths {
    0 = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts/Page/
  }
  dataProcessing {
    20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    20 {
      references {
        table = tt_content
        uid.field = uid
        fieldName = tx_layout_background_image
      }
      as = images
    }
  }
}
```

Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php

$temporaryColumn = array(
    'tx_layout_background_image' => [
        'label' => 'BG Image',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'tx_layout_background_image',
            [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ],
                'overrideChildTca' => [
                    'columns' => [
                        'crop' => [
                            'description' => 'field description',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'types' => [
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                            'showitem' => '
                               --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                               --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
        ),
    ],
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $temporaryColumn
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'layout',
    'tx_layout_background_image',
    'after:layout'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    '--div--;Layout,
    --palette--;;layout',
    '',
    ''
);
```

The Problem is that i just get this in the data array

```
data.tx_layout_background_image => 1 (integer)
```

How can i get the image from this?
I Tried it with treatasreference but i dont get the right image object.

---

**Edit**
With this it seems like its working

```
lib.contentElement {
    dataProcessing.99 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    dataProcessing.99 {
        as = backgroundImages
        references.fieldName = tx_layout_background_image
        references.table = tt_content
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1` you have found in the field is the number of references to this field.
The real relation is stored in another record.

Since inventing FAL (File Abstraction Layer) references to files are no longer stored as path and name of the file but are represented by a record (`sys_file`), where the path and name (and further information) is stored. a relation is done with mm-records in the table `sys_file_reference`. it consists of the fields

- `uid_local` (the `uid` of the `sys_file`-record)
- `uid_foreign` (the `uid` of the related record)
- `tablenames` (name of the table of related record: `tt_content` in your case)
- `fieldname` (name of the field in that record as there might be multiple fields with file relations: your field-name: `tx_layout_background_image` )
- `sorting_foreign` (giving an order if multiple files could be related)
- `table_local` (always `sys_file`)

Now you can make an explicit query on this related records.

---

But you also can use a dataprocessor which can handle it for you:
As you use files it should be a [filesprocessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html) as you used it in your code.

But you missed the correct context.

Either you have inserted the field to the wrong table (`tt_content` instead of `pages`).
Or you used the filesprocessor on the wrong table: the rendering of tt_content records is not done in `page.10` but in `tt_content.<cType>` like:

example:

```
tt_content.my_custom_ctype = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.my_custom_ctype {
   :
   dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
   dataProcessing.10 {
      as = backgroundImages
      references.fieldName = tx_layout_background_image
      references.table = tt_content
   }
}
```

If you wish to add it to every cType you can add it to `lib.contentElement` the prototype for all content elements from where it gets copied/referenced into all cTypes.

```
lib.contentElement {
   dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
   dataProcessing.10 {
      as = backgroundImages
      references.fieldName = tx_layout_background_image
      references.table = tt_content
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank yout. With the TypoScript and the lib.contentElement it seems to work. I would like to have this option in every content element so i have to use tt_content instead of pages or am i wrong? My mistake was the DataProcessor

Comment: if you want to set the background for each content element the new field belongs to `tt_content` if you want to set the background from the complete page the field should be in `pages` record. if you want to set the background of the page from any content element your concept is faulty.

Comment: I have the exact same solution I don't understand why I get an empty array.

Comment: probably your selection is empty. try to debug all fluid variables (`f:debug`) and inspect the typoscript with the TSOB (TypoScript ObjectBrowser)