# How to take the image reference in Fluid TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have created a new content element, but I have a problem with the image field. I have managed to save it in db. There it is saved as a integer. In the fluid it comes back as a integer but I need the image object to display it. I know it must be a typoscript configuration problem but can't seem to solve it.

**tt_content.php**

```
<?php
// Poekmon Element
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
   'tt_content',
   'CType',
    [
        'Pokemon Element',
        'strange_elements',
        'content-target',
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['strange_elements'] = [
    'showitem' => '
          --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
             --palette--;;general,
             header; Main Header,
             bodytext; Main Body,
             tx_selected_pokemon; Choose your pokemon,
             tx_type_pokemon; Pokemon Radio,
             tx_image_pokemon; Pokemon Image,
          --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
             --palette--;;hidden,
             --palette--;;access,
       ',
    'columnsOverrides' => [
       'bodytext' => [
          'config' => [
             'enableRichtext' => true,
             'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
          ],
       ],
    ],
 ];

$newPokemonElFields = [
   'tx_selected_pokemon' => [
      'exclude' => 0,
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.tx_selected_pokemon',
      'config' => [
         'type' => 'select',
         'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
         'items' => [
            ['Pikachu', 'pikachu'],
            ['Squirtle', 'squirtle'],
            ['Bulbasaur', 'bulbasaur'],
            ['Charmander', 'charmander'],
         ],
         'default' => 'pikachu'
      ],
   ],
   'tx_type_pokemon' => [
      'exclude' => 0,
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tt_content.tx_type_pokemon',
      'config' => [
            'type' => 'radio',
            'items' => [
               ['Water', 'water'],
               ['Fire', 'fire'],
               ['Grass', 'grass'],
            ],
      ],
   ],
   'tx_image_pokemon' => [
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.tx_image_pokemon',
      'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', [
         'appearance' => [
             'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.asset_references.tx_image_pokemon'
         ],
     ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['mediafile_ext'])
  ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', $newPokemonElFields);
```

**ext_tables.sql**

```
tx_image_pokemon int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
```

**setup.typoscript**

```
#########################
#### Content Element ####
#########################
lib.contentElement {
    templateRootPaths.200 = EXT:youtube_demo/Resources/Private/Templates/
}
tt_content {
    contenance_elements =< lib.contentElement
    contenance_elements {
        templateName = ContenanceEl
        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
                references {
                    table = tt_content
                    fieldName = tx_image_pokemon
                }
                as = images_pokemon
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the FLUID where you want to render your image? Please provide the information how you tried to output the image from the record.

Comment: Just added the updated code and an image of all the variables in fluid. I find it really weird as a bug since it seems it is excatly what the docs have but I might have missed something :/

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. The ***references.fieldName*** should be ***image*** regarding  how you named the field in ***ext_tables.sql***. Which I find kind of weird since I checked the db and don't see any reference there would apreciate if anyone gave me an explanation to why this is the right way.

```
lib.contentElement {
    templateRootPaths.200 = EXT:youtube_demo/Resources/Private/Templates/
}
tt_content {
    contenance_elements =< lib.contentElement
    contenance_elements {
        templateName = ContenanceEl
        dataProcessing{
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your sql file you defined the field `tx_image_pokemon`. So: where comes the field `images` from? Maybe you used the existing field of tt_content to insert images in the record? then you probably failed the `showitem` definition of your record type. (TCA: types -> yourtype -> showitem = ...fieldlist...) (if you don't show *all* information we can only guess the solution for your problem)

Comment: I don't know which file I can show anymore. I think I have shown all the files involved in making this custom element.

Comment: From references.fieldName = tx_image_pokemon To references.fieldName = image  fixed the problem!

Comment: `showitem` is part of the TCA, Therefore it belongs into your `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`. But you missed to use your image field and so only the default `image` field is editable for any editor while working on your CE.

Answer (score 0):

If you just access the field of the file reference you will get the counter of references.

you need to use a [`FilesProcessor`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72893718/6796354)

Comment: tt_content {
    contenance_elements =< lib.contentElement
    contenance_elements {
        templateName = ContenanceEl
        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
                references {
                    table = tt_content
                    fieldName = tx_image_pokemon
                }
                as = images_pokemon
        }
    }
}

Comment: It comes back as an empty array :(